# Show Calendar view on page using rest api

Tags: sharepoint

I want to show calendar.aspx view  on the page using rest api without using server code or webpart. 
Is there any way to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the client side scripting using the Jquery and fullcalendar.io plugin to display the calendar view.

There will be no server side code required and you can store all your data in existing calendar of your sharepoint. Only for rendering we will use the Jquery full calendar plugin. 
Below function retreive will get the data from the sharepoint calendar list.

```
function Retreive() {
var listUrl = "../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UpcomingEvents";
$.ajax({
    url: listUrl,
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        $select: "Title,Description,StartTime,EndTime,AllDayEvent,Recurrence,Id"
    },
    headers: {
        accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function(i) {
            currObj = this;
            var fADE = currObj.AllDayEvent;
            if (fADE != null) {
                if (fADE == 0) {
                    thisADE = false
                } else thisADE = true;
            }
            var thisID = currObj.Id;
            var thisTitle = currObj.Title;
            var thisRecurrence = currObj.Recurrence;
            var thisDesc = currObj.Description;
            var x = new Date(parseInt(currObj.StartTime.substr(6)));
            var y = new Date(parseInt(currObj.EndTime.substr(6)));
            ele.push({
                title: currObj.Title,
                id: currObj.Id,
                start: x,
                description: currObj.Description,
                end: y,
                allDay: thisADE,
            });
        });
        BindCalendar();
    }
});}
```

function bindcalendar will load the data from the array 'ele' into the calendar plugin

```
function BindCalendar() {
var calendarioDiv = $('#calendar');
var fullCalendar = calendarioDiv.fullCalendar({
    events: ele,
    error: function() {
        alert('Error');
    },
    editable: false,
    firstDay: 0,
    monthNames: ['JANUARY', 'FEBRUARY',
        'MARCH', 'APRIL', 'MAY',
        'JUNE', 'JULY', 'AUGUST', 'SEPTEMBER',
        'OCTOBER', 'NOVEMBER', 'DECEMBER'
    ],
    dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'
    ],
    dayNamesShort: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    allDay: true
});}
```

See Reference article- 
http://kalashnikovtechnoblogs.blogspot.in/2015/08/display-calendar-using-jquery-full.html

Comment: Thanks  for the solution. But does this will returns the overlaid event from different calendars as well. Also if it is possible to do the  same without third party js refrence.

Comment: No this will return the events only from the calendar 'UpcomingEvents' list. But if you want to return the events from the multiple calendars you can perform multiple async ajax call on each calendar and store it in the 'ele' array which will be single data source for binding to jquery calendar

Comment: Yes this is true, but my site collection has multiple sites and subsites. So i don't have  information to where the calendars and what are the names and urls. With overlaid it will show all the events in one master calendar. So if it is possible to show this master calendar.aspx view  on the page with some rest api or jquery.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can store the calendar name and the url in configuration list and you can use it in your master page to retrieve the events. But if there are multiple sites and subsites you might have to consider to recursive list all the subsites and get the lists with the calendar type.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have created config list and this list has calendar names and  url. Now i am getting items from this list  using REST API, on the success method  i am firing another loop which get items from child calendar and adding  in array variable. The issue is that when i am adding items to array it will only store last items value. Please refer code. How can call one rest api method inside another. Please look the code i am doing

Comment: I have used the above code exactly. Now the problem is coming that it is showing just one value from ele array object not all(i have 4 array values) but it is showing just one event